# PHP syntax with file_put_contents

Tags: php, syntax

I try to put

```
  $string .= '(\''.$idURL.'\', \''.$premierP.'\', \''.$prefixe.'\', \''.$matches1['0'].'\', \''.$matches2[0].'\'),\\n';
```

in a file (for construt sql lines) with `file_put_contents($file, $string);`, but it's doesn't work, what's wrong ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, apart from maybe double escaping `\n` and having it within single quotes and not double (the `\n` in single)

Comment: You know you can mix single quotes with double to avoid backslash mess? i.e. ` foo(" 'bar' ")` (SO breaks this) instead of `foor(' \'bar\' ')`

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does that mean? What *does* it do? Any errors? *Anything*?

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me. I have tested like below.

```
<?php 

$file = 'test.txt';
$idURL ='test';
$premierP = 'test';
$prefixe = 'test';
$matches1['0'] = 'test';
$matches2[0] = 'test';
$string .= '(\''.$idURL.'\', \''.$premierP.'\', \''.$prefixe.'\', \''.$matches1['0'].'\', \''.$matches2[0].'\'),\\n';

file_put_contents($file, $string);
?>
```